# Removing whitespaces from a string

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
string="   this    is a string     "
```

What is the simplest way to remove duplicated whitespaces and get the following string:

```
string="this is a string"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line should work for the given example:

```
awk '$1=$1' <<< $string
```

see test:

```
kent$  x="   this    is a string     "

kent$  awk '$1=$1' <<< $x
this is a string
```

Comment: much better than my `sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'` which only solved 2 of the three parts... +1

Comment: @FredrikPihl it could be shorter `s/^ *\| *$//` but we still need `s/ \+/ /g`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to achieve this without using awk?

Comment: yes, other tool, or bash itself.  Personally I just thought awk would be the simplest. @Doppelganger

Comment: `cat <<< $string` is also simple

Answer (score 2):

No need to use external binaries like Awk. You can do that in Bash alone.

```
string="   this    is a string     "
IFS=' ' read -a __ <<< "$string"; string="${__[@]}"
echo "$string"
this is a string
```

Another solution:

```
shopt -s extglob  ## need to be set only once.
string=${string##*([[:blank:]])}; string=${string%%*([[:blank:]])}; string=${string//+([[:blank:]])/ }
```

Or just specific to spaces (`$'\x20'`)

```
string=${string##*( )}; string=${string%%*( )}; string=${string//+( )/ }
```

Comment: echo $string gives me `{__[@]}` bash version 4.2.45

Comment: @FredrikPihl Sorry forgot $. I changed the parameter's name from `string`.

Comment: yeah, I saw that 2 seconds after I hit send. Nice usage of array and the IFS variable but you have to agree that the awk solution is cleaner :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl Only slower and needs a subshell :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution using echo :

```
string=$(echo $string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the string character by character. Whenever you get two consecutive whitespaces, shift the array one character backwards

Answer (score 0):

Make the shell's [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) work for you (assuming a default value for `IFS`).

```
string="   this    is a string     "
arr=($string)
printf -v string2 "%s" "${arr[*]}"
echo _${string2}_
_this is a string_
```